# I don't understand the point of the <article> tag

Tags: html

What does it do? You put it around text, and it doesn't do anything.

`<article> </article>` has the same effect as `<p> </p>`

Comment: The article tag is used to separate the content inside the tag from the rest of the site. The best use I can think of is if a site has some content that can be syndicated. For instance, the Microsoft website might use the article tag for daily news information that also goes into an RSS feed.

Comment: HTML is about **semantics**. `article` is a more specific tag than `p` and hence describes some content better. Links: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/article.html, http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/. In generell, all (most) new tags introduced by HTML5 are of semantic nature (e.g. `section`, `nav`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<article>` is just a block-level element introduced in HTML5 for [semantics](http://html5doctor.com/lets-talk-about-semantics/).

Think of it just like the `<blockquote>` element. You could use `<div class="blockquote">`, but why? `<blockquote>` is already there and does the job. Instead of having `<div>`s nested six deep, you can use elements that have a little more meaning.

Take a look at what the [HTML5 reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/article.html) says:

> The article element represents a section of content that forms an independent part of a document or site; for example, a magazine or newspaper article, or a blog entry.

Comment: You can't really replace `<article>` with `<p class="article">` as the two elements have different permitted contents, compare [`<article>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/article.html#article-content-model)'s and [`<p>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html#p-content-model)'s.

Comment: @muistooshort: Sorry, bad example. `<div>` is probably better here.

Comment: I used `<p>` because that's in the question. The point is that both the semantics and the allowed content are important.

Comment: Cheers for that semantics link. I agree Divya Manian on "Our Pointless Pursuit Of Semantic Value".

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, HTML is intended to convey contents and semantics. `<article>` sets off a section of the page that represents an entire independently-distributable piece of content, whereas `<p>` just sets off a paragraph within a page.

From the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element):

> The `article` element represents a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

Comment: And here I thought it was to provide another tag to attach CSS too.

Comment: That's one possible use, though it could just as easily be done with `<div class="article">` as people have been doing for years. What's really useful about semantics is that they offer a more standardized way to mark semantics, which is good news for automated tools like search engines and accessibility tools.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML `<article>` tag is used to represent an article. More specifically, the content within the `<article>` tag is independent from the other content on the site (even though it could be related). where as `<p>`  tag is used for defining a paragraph within a page

We only have a title and some content, but it’s enough to make sense on its own

```
<article>
        <h1>Apple</h1>
        <p>The <b>apple</b> is the pomaceous fruit of the apple tree...</p>
        ...
</article>
```